# multiple figure in latex with captions

Tags: latex

How can I insert multiple figures each of them has a caption and label, without using minipage.

I wrote this code, but just there is one caption :(

```
\begin{figure}[htp]

  \centering

  \label{figur}\caption{equation...}

  \begin{tabular}{cc}

    % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit3185.eps}&

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit3183.eps}\\

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit1501.eps}&

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit23185.eps}\\

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit23183.eps}&

    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit21501.eps}\\

  \end{tabular}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: You know, there is a [stack exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) for latex questions...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about latex.

Answer (score 20):

Look at the Subfloats section of http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \label{figur}\caption{equation...}

  \subfloat[Subcaption 1]{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit3185.eps}}
  \subfloat[Subcaption 2]{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit3183.eps}}
  \\
  \subfloat[Subcaption 3]{\label{figur:3}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit1501.eps}}
  \subfloat[Subcaption 4]{\label{figur:4}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit23185.eps}}
  \\
  \subfloat[Subcaption 5]{\label{figur:5}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit23183.eps}}
  \subfloat[Subcaption 6]{\label{figur:6}\includegraphics[width=60mm]{explicit21501.eps}}

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of multiple figures that I used recently in Latex.
You need to call these packages

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig})


\begin{figure}[H]%

    \centering

    \subfloat[Row1]{{\includegraphics[scale=.36]{1.png} }}%

    \subfloat[Row2]{{\includegraphics[scale=.36]{2.png} }}%

    \subfloat[Row3]{{\includegraphics[scale=.36]{3.png} }}%
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Row4]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.37]{4.png} }}%

    \subfloat[Row5]{{\includegraphics[scale=0.37]{5.png} }}%

    \caption{Multiple figures in latex.}%

    \label{fig:MFL}%

\end{figure}
```